# How to remove background-color in tailwindcss?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm wondering how can I remove background color from an existing `div` for a specific `xl` screen size? I want something like this `background-color:unset`, is this possible with `tailwind.css`?

```html
<div class="fixed bottom-0 bg-baseorange p-4 left-0 w-full z-10 xl: bg-none xl:absolute lg:absolute xl:bottom-22 xl:right-20 lg:bottom-22 lg:right-20">
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `xl:bg-transparent`.

In Tailwind, the class `bg-transparent` sets the css property `background-color: transparent;`

Tailwind documentation:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Comment: This is the correct answer!